# Angularjs and populating fields/placeholder blinking

Tags: html, angularjs

I do know that Angularjs populates fields via their model.

Html loads first:

```
<input type="text" data-ng-model="values.myValue" placeholder="trololol">
```

Then the JavaScript:

```
$scope.values = {};
$scope.values.myValue = 'herro my value';
```

This works, but there is a blink second where the placeholder displays then updates with the value 'herro my value'.

I'm wondering if there is a way I can put the value straight into the html without screwing up the angularjs model? For example.

```
<input type="text" value="herro my value" data-ng-model="values.myValue" placeholder="trololol">
```

Then when the JavaScript loads, the model takes over. Is this a safe way of getting rid of this blink on page load?

Answer (score 1):

The ng-cloak attribute should prevent this:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Ahh this seems like exactly what I need. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `display: none;` on your `body` tag and adding a run block to angular:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
.run(function() {
 document.body.style.display = "block"
});
```

The difference is now that the user is getting a blank screen now until angular is loaded.

Run block example: https://www.ng-book.com/p/Angular-Module-Loading/#run-blocks

Comment: Ahh interesting. I will try it out.

Comment: Are you using ````ngRoute```` or ````ui-router````? If you are using this then you can make use of states. If angular is initialized, then the proper state will be loaded and shown.  Have in mind that users without javascript enabled won't be able to use your site/application properly.

Comment: I currently do not use routing in angularjs, I render diffrent urls server side then do dynamic updating on the page via angularjs. Bit of a hybrid solution. I'd like to load the default values server side, I currently have to load empty inputs then populate them as it stands.